# How to read txt file and save as a single string in java in order to split it by a certain character

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-7, text-manipulation

I'm new to to java language & am finding trouble finding to:

```
1. read a txt file
2. save entire txt file as single string
3. once I have the txt file content as a string, break the string (by a certain character such as a new line) into an array of strings that I can work with.
```

If you may include the import statements that are required, that would be helpful as well as a new java programmer.

I was working with the `BufferedReader` but I believe that only gives me the current line to work with.

I did see that `BufferedReader` had a `lines()` method which returns a stream of `Stream<String>`.

Comment: What did you try? Did you Google "Java read file" etc?

Comment: for reading as string see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-do-i-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file

Comment: Why do you want to store it as a single string? That is an odd requirement.

Comment: you can read the text file directly in an array

Comment: This is probably homework, and you are asking us to do it for you.

Comment: The error is already in the premise. Why insisting on reading a file into a single `String`, if you already know that you actually want an array…

Comment: I was thinking of grabbing all of the text file contents as a string, trimming it & removing new lines & tabs for certain types of files I'm working with.

I did read some docs, but a lot of the examples don't show the packages you need to import. I'm also getting used to reading the java docs.


Yeah - very novice question, but hey that's why I am here to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Files#lines` returns a stream of all the lines in the file. You could join these lines to a single string, and then split it according to the separator:

```
String separator = ":"; // for example...
String entireFile = 
    Files.lines(Paths.get("file.txt")).collect(Collectors.joining());
String[] separated = entireFile.split(separator);
```